Question on the poloidal and toroidal Magnetic field lines close to a astrophysical black hole
I'm trying to fully understand the force-free region near a Kerr black hole. A common picture is depicted as Figure 1, 1.

In this context, a generic magnetic field is:
$$\vec{B} = (\vec{B}_{P})+\vec{B}_{T} = (\vec{B}_{r}+\vec{B}_{\theta})+\vec{B}_{\phi}, \tag{1}$$
where $\vec{B}_{P}$ is called poloidal magnetic field and $\vec{B}_{T}$ toroidal magnetic field.
Now, the paradigm is: in far regions from the ergosphere (notably in the accretion disk), the magnetic field is almost poloidal. Then, due to the MHD conditions, the these poloidal field lines are advected close to the black hole, by accretion. Then, close to the black hole (and notably inside the ergosphere), the frame-dragging effect is huge and these poloidal field lines become twisted; so twisted that, as far as I understood the physics, they became pure toroidal field lines.
My question is: why are poloidal field lines depicted in the figure, inside the red boundary? Shouldn't be just a pure toroidal magnetic field region?

1 https://www.mdpi.com/2075-4434/10/4/89 (Figure 1, page 4)
